# Cannot find name 'Cheerio' in @types/enzyme/index.d.t

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cheerio

I get this error when attempting to run my Node application:

> C:/Me/MyApp/node_modules/@types/enzyme/index.d.ts
> (351,15): Cannot find name 'Cheerio'.

I came across a post that suggests I should be using `cheerio` rather than `Cheerio` but the error seems to be coming from a package in the `node_modules` folder, not my code so I'm not sure what to do here. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Make sure that you have installed cheerio with the `npm install cheerio` command. The `node_modules` folder is the place where all packages are stored and is where cheerio will be stored once you install it.

Answer (score 0):

In @types/enzyme/index.d.ts:

```
render(): Cheerio;
```

should be:

```
render(): cheerio.Cheerio;
```

@types/enzyme version >= 3.10.7 fix this bug. This error disappears after updating package.json like this:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "enzyme":"3.10.0",
   "@types/enzyme":"3.10.7"
}
```